# How to import data from another model to use like a Field select in a new redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

Im new using React-Redux and i have some problems in this particular case.

How can i get information from another table?, and show it like an select option in a new form to associate with each other.

```html
class EmployeeForm extends Component{

\.....

<Form>
  
  ...Some another fields like name, gender, etc. The form is for
  add new employee (Just for context)...
  
  <Field
    name="charge"
    fullWidth
    component="select"
    label="charge"
  >

**That's i want! , take information from the Api, and show it like an option to associate employee and job tables**

    <option value="cake_decorator">Cake Decorator</option>
    <option value="chef">Chef</option>
    <option value="delivery_driver">Delivery Driver</option>
  </Field>
</Form>

...../
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'employeeForm',
  validate
})(EmployeeForm)
```

**Extra**
I tried to use fetch, but could not put the data in the form(Only show the Promise in console). Anyway, i would like to follow the redux pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const sampleArray = [
 {value: 'cake_decorator', label: 'Cake Decorator'},
 {value: 'chef', label: 'Cake Decorator'}
]
```

// This is form A

```
   <Field
    name="charge"
    fullWidth
    component="select"
    label="charge"
    >
    {sampleArray.map(item)=>{
     <option value={item.value}>{Item.label}</option>
    }}
  </Field>
```

[getformvalue in reduxform will help](https://redux-form.com/6.0.2/docs/api/selectors.md/)

Form B

const associatedArray = useSelector((state)=>state.form.formA)

associatedArray.charge --> this is the selected value of that field and your can fill your list on the bases of this value.

Comment: You can make a dedicated file of constant lists and import.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand yet. Where does it connect to the store? Because I want to show all the objects stored in the db, so... the actions and the reducers?

Comment: Just write down "const associatedArray = useSelector((state)=>state.form.formA)" and you will be clear on that